# What is clientId, authTokenEndpoint, clientKey for accessing Azure Data Lake?

Tags: java, azure, azure-data-lake

I am writing a test application to read file from AzureData Lake. I have created the account and the resource, as well as uploading the file. I am trying to create a client using the following code (as described in the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-get-started-java-sdk). Where do I get those values from exactly?
Thanks

```
String clientId = "FILL-IN-HERE";
String authTokenEndpoint = "FILL-IN-HERE";
String clientKey = "FILL-IN-HERE";

AccessTokenProvider provider = new ClientCredsTokenProvider(authTokenEndpoint, clientId, clientKey);
// full account FQDN, not just the account name
String accountFQDN = "FILL-IN-HERE";
ADLStoreClient client = ADLStoreClient.createClient(accountFQDN, provider);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using [Azure Active Directory authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-service-to-service-authenticate-using-active-directory) with Azure Data Lake.

Login Azure portal->click Azure Active Directory->click App registrations->find your application(or create a new one)

**ClientId**

[image]

**clientKey**(Click Certificates&secrets->click new client secret->click add) The client secret is the clientKey.

[image]

**authTokenEndpoint** Click Endpoints

[image]

Refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-service-to-service-authenticate-using-active-directory) for more details.